# `Unsupported code path for UIScene-based application` in iOS 14

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I just got macOS Big Sur Beta 1 on my Mac installed with the latest Xcode 12 Beta Version.
Currently, I'm developing an app for iOS 11.0 with UIKit (I don't know if this information matters for the question). The iPhone I'm running the app on, is on iOS 14 Beta 1.

Whenever the app is running, I noticed this in the debug console:
`2020-06-28 20:36:57.689922+0200 Appname[4231:891294] [Assert] Unsupported code path for UIScene-based application.`

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: FWIW, this message appears on WatchOS 7 Beta 1 too.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?  I've just removed the storyboard from a simple app using the steps outlined in the Medium article "Creating Apps Without Storyboards in iOS 13".  All works fine, but it's started giving me the same assert. 

[Medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-apps-without-storyboards-in-ios-13-fc9550bb9c12)

Comment: First, it's just a console message, probably for internal use at Apple. Second, I'm debugging something completely different, but am running into this exact same message in **both** Xcode 12 beta 2 **and** Xcode 11.6 - against devices running iPadOS 14 beta 2 I'd say don't worry about it. You can always mute these console messages by setting the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE variable in your build variables.